# Excel Sheet Format, Showing Parent/Child nodes & Information

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, format, spreadsheet

I currently have the following format in excel:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to display this information in a 'prettier' way?  I will have many nodes and many 'information columns'.

Comment: How did you load this? Is it from an XML file? Are you talking about a VBA procedure or building XLST template? You need to supply more info

Comment: Is this supposed to represent a tree or other graph structure?  Can you describe the schema of the data, and maybe we can recommend a solution?

Comment: @dbmitch , It is just done manually in excel. a copy and paste job from different sources unfortunately.

Comment: @jehad , it is a tree structure, there will be many nodes and sub nodes. But these nodes will have columns pertaining to each node, such as 'in column J, visited today and each node would have a Y/N answer.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: have you tried searching for e.g. "tree structure in Excel"? I'm sure there are plenty of templates available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wouldn't recommend Excel/Spreadsheet for representing structured data.  You can get a lot more mileage from a simple database, like sqlite.

But, if you must have a spreadsheet, for tree structured data, I would fill out the spreadsheet completely (even if the data looks repetitive), here is an abstract example:

Tree to be represented:

```
RootX
  |- Node1
       |- Node1.1
            |- Node1.1.1
                 |- Node1.1.1.1 - DataXYZ
                 |- Node1.1.1.2
                 |- Node1.1.1.3 - DataABC
       |- Node1.2
            |- Node1.2.1
                 |- Node1.2.1.1
  |- Node2
       |- Node2.1
            |- Node2.1.1
                 |- Node2.1.1.1

RootY
  |- Node3
       |- Node3.1
            |- Node3.1.1
                 |- Node3.1.1.1 - DataHIJ
            |- Node3.1.2
                 |- Node3.1.2.1
```

The spreadsheet will look like this:

```
Columns   A      B      C        D          E            F
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.1  DataXYZ
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.2
          RootX  Node1  Node1.1  Node1.1.1  Node1.1.1.3  DataABC
          RootX  Node1  Node1.2  Node1.2.1  Node1.2.1.1

          RootX  Node2  Node2.1  Node2.1.1  Node2.1.1.1

          RootY  Node3  Node3.1  Node3.1.1  Node3.1.1.1  DataHIJ
          RootY  Node3  Node3.1  Node3.1.2  Node3.1.2.1
```

The reason is that this completion of data entry allows you to filter and apply formatting, based on any level of the tree structure.

Comment: thanks Jehad! How about if I want data to pertain to each node? Where could that fit in?

Comment: You're welcome @Jonnyboi.  If I understand you correctly, I guess add a column to the right (in my example, a new column F) to enter the data for the node represented by that row.  (I'll make a small edit to the above to illustrate.)  In my opinion, it's just a matter of flattening your tree representation into a 2D table.  As, "Máté Juhász" has suggested in a comment above, you can find alternative ways to input trees into Excel, which may work for you, so have a look.  My recommendation is just based on my experience of managing large amounts of data and works for me.

Comment: thanks :) , know of any macro I can use to get my data from my format to yours? lol

Comment: I don't really know of nor do I have a library of macros; I tend to do complex analysis and data storage in databases.  Also, depends on your data.  I'm not sure what you have to begin with and the macro you'd need will depend on your starting point.  You could start a new question on this website if you need advice on where to being, or write your own macro (VBA is not too difficult) and feel free to ask if/when you need help.